# Starting iOS simulator from command line fails with error code 60

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, simulator, xcrun

I'm trying to boot an iOS simulator from the command line using the following command:

```
xcrun simctl boot 81C46931-BFAB-4669-87FC-9E45E4634196
```

Unfortunately this fails with the following error:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (code=60):
Unable to boot the iOS Simulator.
launchd failed to respond.
```

Googling for this error lead nowhere.

One thing I found is this error happens for iOS Simulator with iOS 7. iOS Simulator with iOS 8 can boot fine with the above command.

As anybody already encountered this error? If so, how did you fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you know that characters after *boot* from?

Comment: By running `xcrun simctl list devices`. It list all the simulators devices with their GUID.